# What is the use of tableview's delegate method cellforrowatindexpath in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i am fresher and i am doing my app in swift language and i want to know that what is the difference between

```
func cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell/
```

delegate methods in UITableView?

Answer (score 2):

As a one line answer to the question,

The first method

```
func cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
```

is `not tableView delegate method`. It an instance method in `UITableView Class`. Which is used to get a cell from `tableView` instance by passing `indexPath` as parameter. So you will be using this method on a `tableView` instance.

The second method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

is the datasource method of `UITableView` that is used to populate tableview cells. This method will be implemented in the datasource/delegate class.

Answer (score 1):

`func cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?` is a UITableView method, it is used to get a cell at a given time when the tableview is defined. For instance, it can be used to check is a cell is visible. If it is not visible this method will return nil.

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` is a UITableViewDataSource method, it is used to define all the cells of the tableview, so that it can know what to display.

Comment: what do you mean by "cell visible"?

Comment: @KrishSolanki, for instance if your tableview contains 100 rows, only a few of them will be displayed (like 10 or so), the rest is not displayed until you scroll. The first method will return nil if the cell is not currently on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The first method

```
func cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
```

It is an `instance` method in `UITableView Class`. And it is used to get a cell from tableView instance by passing indexPath as parameter .

and the second one

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

is the `datasource` method of `UITableView` and it is one of the require method in `UITableView`.

Thank you.